# Excel: How to compare a list of values against another list of values

Tags: excel, vlookup

I need to compare two lists, A and B. I want to see how often a value from list A appears in list B.

Ex: 3 unique values in list A (fox, cat, dog,) and 5 values in list B (fox, cat, dog, dog, fox).

I need the values of the output to look like this:

```
fox: 2
cat: 1
dog: 2
```

In my excel file, I have greater than 10,000 values for list A and B. So I need to find a way to compare both lists together and count how often a value in list A is found in list B.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want COUNTIF():

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)
```

[image]